# ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, odbc, instantclient

I just installed the Oracle instant client on my laptop, and get this when I try to connect via ODBC in C#.  The machine has had 9.2 and 10.2 installed in the past.

Why does this error appear?  In my connection string, can I tell it to ignore the Oracle NLS settings?

Comment: Did you set ORACLE_HOME?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was to find the registry key named NLS_LANG under:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE

and rename it to anything else.  I put an "x" at the end.  This key is left over from a full install of Oracle.  The instant client ODBC  works properly now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, at my machine the NLS_LANG key was not in `ORACLE`, but here:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\oracle\KEY_OraClient11g_home1_32bit`

Renamed it by appending "_X", problem solved :-)

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem with oracle's obiee admin tool, when i tried to import tables, but only on 
32bit pc's. found that the 32bit pc's stored the nls_lang key in two places in the registry, one under the ORACLE key and another one under the oracle home key. renamed  the one from the ORACLE key as noted above and this fixed my problem. on  my 64bit  pc there was no nls_lang
key under ORACLE, and thats probably why i didn't have the same problem on the 64bit pc's.

updated my oracle sr with this url...